# PHP get username from Basic Authorization

Tags: php, .htaccess, basic-authentication

In my .htaccess file, I have:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user

<Files .htaccess>
deny from all 
</Files>
```

and the .htpasswd file has a valid user/password.

When I go to a PHP file, I need to get the username that was used to access the page. The PHP is accessed ok, so I know the user/pass are working, but I can't seem to get the username extracted.

I have tried both `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, but both are empty. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways PHP can store the username, so maybe give something like this a try.

```
<?php

$username_extracted = retrieve_php_username();

function retrieve_php_username() {
  $username = '';
  // Try to get the login name from the $_SERVER variable.
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) || isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
    $authorization_header = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
      $authorization_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
    }
    // If using CGI on Apache with mod_rewrite, the forwarded HTTP header appears in the redirected HTTP headers.
    elseif (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && !empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
      $authorization_header = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
    }
    // Resemble PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW for a Basic authentication from
    // the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header. See http://www.php.net/manual/features.http-auth.php
    if (!empty($authorization_header)) {
      list($username_temp, $userpass_temp) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($authorization_header, 6)));
      $username = $username_temp;
    }
  }
  // Check other possible values in different keys of the $_SERVER superglobal
  elseif (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $username = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'];
  }
  elseif (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $username = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
  }
  elseif (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    $username = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_PHP_AUTH_USER'];
  }
  elseif (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
  }
  return $username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had an override in `.htaccess` to run php 5.5 and it was running under CGI which prevented pass-through of the authorization variables.